# Store Repeated Data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (Key tinyint, Value bigint).
There are a billion rows for each distinct Key value and only about 100 distinct Key values.

Is there a way to not have to store Key in the every row without breaking this up into multiple tables?

Comment: You want to save storing 1 byte per row? You need some way to identify which key a value belongs to - can you think of some way that would be < 1 byte? I can't...

Comment: @AaronBertrand 100 gigabytes for the 100 billion rows in this table.

Comment: Still need a way to identify the data. CustomerID is expensive in an Orders table, too, but I don't know a cheaper way to tie those two things together.

Comment: <s>Perhaps</s> Almost certainly bad advice, but if there is a static number of Keys, you could use either a single table for each key, or a single column for each key?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is encoding the key into the BIGINT value - e.g. 1, 1000 becomes 10000000001000 and 255, 789 becomes 2550000000000789 (roughly, tough to tell in mobile how many digits is). But man is that ugly and so not worth it. I would first implement data compression - which will save you at least 4 bytes per row for all values that could fit in int, smallint or tinyint.

Comment: So the proposed new structure is 100 heap tables. Each heap containing 1bn rows with a single column with a `bigint` value? What kind of queries do you do against this data? Purely aggregation? Or are there other columns too?

Comment: How distinct is the Value column in each Key group? If it reduces the row counts enough, making a look-up table based on SHA1 hashes of the Key and Value pair might work for you, even though it outputs a VARBINARY(8000) column. I use this for multi-column de-duplication. Is your example simplified?

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving it how it is, but using columnstore, perhaps. The effectiveness will depend on the style of usage, but you may find it compresses a lot better, having a useful impact.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the `Key` and `Value` into a [dense](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/DPDecimal.html) [binary](http://www.quadibloc.com/arch/ar010104.htm) encoding.  You'd be better off doing this in the application, most likely.  Define the table's column to be `binary()` of just the right length to hold the packed values.  3 digits (key) + 10 digits (value) gives about 7 bytes for the column (rounding up), down from the 9 bytes needed for a `tinyint` and `bigint`.  With the `Key` as the high values the rows will be in the same clustered sequence as currently.

I've little experience dealing with binary columns so indexing, clustering, partitioning and defining good predicates for lookups may prove .. "challenging".